c++ crash self function args capture
I have a large C++ unix program that crashes randomly, but we can't provide customers with a debug build. I want to capture details of all function calls and their parameters at the time of a crash and save this information to a text file. Is there a standard method to achieve this?
One approach I considered is to create a stack object at the beginning of each function. This object would store the function's parameters in its constructor and release them in its destructor. Is there some library for same or some easy way to do it ?
update:  I need this for a Unix program, but the issue occurs in the customer's environment with a large file that we never receive. We are prohibited from sharing debug builds with the customer, but we are allowed to generate log files.

"Is there a standard method to achieve this?" - no. This is going to depend on which compiler you are using, what kind of debug info it can save outside of your exe, what kind of logging you are using, any need to do stack-walking (which is also compiler-specific), etc. "One approach I considered is to create a stack object at the beginning of each function" - that would be very tedious and highly inefficient at best.

Any suggestion to achieve this @RemyLebeau as I don't want to touch code  in all of these files

Logging, logging and more logging. A lot of it.

You might want to start with mentioning the target OS in your question/tags.

On Linux you may collect a coredump when executable crashes, that can be examined in gdb (together with debug build)

And I assume that you build with a lot of warnings enabled, and the program builds cleanly without any warnings? What kind of unit-testing do you have for the program? Do you run with a sanitizer to test?

Also, was there a point where it worked without these crashes? If you follow the commits in your VCS backward, what have happened between then and now?

I need this for a Unix program, but the issue occurs in the customer's environment with a large input file that we never receive. We are prohibited from sharing debug builds with the customer, but we are allowed to generate log files.

If the customer really want to fix it, and the logs or possible crash-dumps (core etc.) doesn't help, then they need to either provide the input causing the crash, or allowing one of your developers to come to them to debug in their environment.

@Yksisarvinen: on Windows I do a lot of debugging of release builds. The release build just needs to be built with symbols. Is that different on Linux?

@ThomasWeller You can build release with debug symbols, I assumed OP doesn't want that, since that would generally have similar disadvantages as providing debug build. But with gdb there is no need to send debug symbols to customer, you can have customer build without symbols that crashes (producing core dump) and use local build with symbols to debug it.

@Yksisarvinen: so on Linux, the symbols are directly inside the executable, not in a separate file (like PDB on WIndows)?

@ThomasWeller As far as I know, yes. At least that's the default I've always seen. But I never delved into details of creating executables, so there might be something like that too.

coredumps tend to be very large and may contain confidential information that your customer doesn't want to share. A traceback along the call stack from the point of failure is a much nicer way to find recalcitrant runtime bugs which only show up very rarely. Fortran and Modula2 both have native support for traceback on runtime faults which gives you what failed where and the calling sequence leading up to it. I thought C++23 also offered this functionality now although you may have to back off some of the more aggressive optimisations.


I want to capture details of all function calls and their parameters [presumably including pointers and the pointed-to memory] at the time of a crash and save this information to a text file. Is there a standard method to achieve this? [emphasis added]

Core dumps would be the standard way to achieve this (though perhaps not a standardized way, as it seems OS dependent). Most stack-tracing options appear not to support function argument values (only listing the types), though I've not looked into that many of them. You can find a table of several options in this answer.
